# Is there a way for an app to implement the "Manage Space" API?

Tags: android, storage

Under Settings > Application Manager > *appname*, you will usually see a "Clear data" button under "Storage". But for some apps, such as Google Play Services, it's been replaced by a "Manage Space" button which takes you to another activity that lets you pick and choose what data you clear.

Is there a way to do this with a regular app, or is it restricted to system apps? Googling was of no help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the Activity you want to launch for this purpose in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".my.manage.space.Activity"
    ... />
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#space

Note that your mileage may vary: in my quick testing, this does not appear to be working on emulators with APIs 25 or 26, but does work on 19 and 23, so the behavior may have changed (although I can't find any bugs or change logs about this).

Hope that helps!